# How do I install moodle with the CodeRunner module on windows localhost?

Tags: windows, moodle, coderunner

I'm study and try about moodle now and have installed moodle on windows localhost
though I'm not really understand of how it works.

Now I want to try install CodeRunner https://github.com/trampgeek/CodeRunner moodle question type on this moodle so I can made a programming question that can compile the submitted program and compare it with the testcase I provide to check if the program is right or not, but I have no idea how to do it, all documentation I got on Coderunner is in Linux not windows.

I'm new in moodle admin btw, anyone can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of CodeRunner can be installed on Moodle under Windows just by unzipping the supplied question type and question behaviour zip archives into the Moodle's question/type and question/behaviour folders respectively. However you can't use the built-in Runguard sandbox under Windows, so you'll have to set up a separate machine running the Jobe sandbox (which runs only under Linux) if you wish to make any serious use of CodeRunner. [The plugin is initially configured to connect to a Jobe server at the University of Canterbury in order to run jobs, but that provides a limited service that's useful for preliminary testing only.]

I'm the CodeRunner developer, BTW.